# My R scripts perfectly work when running , but when I use the same scripts in R markdown get an error "does not exist in current working directory"

Tags: r, google-drive-api, r-markdown

My R scripts perfectly work when running when in scripts file in R studio, but when I use the same scripts in R markdown get an error; file "does not exist in current working directory"
Both are in the same wd.
What may be the reason?.

Note: All my work do in google drive offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because R looks for files relative to the current working directory - by default `Sys.getenv("HOME")`, whereas `knitr` looks in the same directory as the Rmarkdown file.

The solution is to specify the correct full or relative path to files in the RMarkdown code.

Answer (score 2):

This is what the new **here** R package was designed for. It always looks at the root of the R project directory (which is what "here" refers to). It doesn't matter if your Rmarkdown file is in a subdirectory.

```
library(here)
here("file_i_want.csv")
```

This will work the same regardless of if you use R scripts or Rmarkdown

More details here (pun intended):
https://github.com/jennybc/here_here